# Running a Dredge Model Subset from clogit

Tags: r, survival-analysis, model-comparison

I am trying to run a dredge on my full model `clogit` (from package `survival`) but R keeps crashing every time I attempt it. I just get an error message saying, "R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated."

```
library(survival)
FullModel <- clogit(OBSERVED ~ Canopy + distgr_sca + Near_Hwy3 + strata(PID1), Compiled)
library(MuMIn)
dredge(FullModel)
```

This is my code. Any ideas on why this is crashing, or other ways I can go about running a full dredge on my model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`clogit` seems to crash R when no *strata* is specified in the model formula or when `strata()` is the only model term. You need to tell `dredge` to keep `strata(PID1)` in all models and restrict the subsets to have minimum 3 variables:

```
dredge(fm0, eval = T, fixed = "strata(id)", m.min = 3)
```

reproducible example:

```
library(survival)
library(MuMIn)

## from example(clogit)
resp <- levels(logan$occupation)
n <- nrow(logan)
indx <- rep(1:n, length(resp))
logan2 <- data.frame(logan[indx,], id = indx, tocc = factor(rep(resp, each=n)))
logan2$case <- (logan2$occupation == logan2$tocc)
fm <- clogit(case ~ tocc + tocc:education + strata(id), logan2, na.action = "na.fail")
##

dredge(fm, fixed = "strata(id)", m.min = 3)
```